# Using FPDF - not working on XP laptop

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to use FPDF on my server and part of that is downloading an image file that is placed in the PDF. The code is working perfectly on one machine and a server, however when using another XP laptop I'm getting these error messages.

`Warning: imagecreatefromgif(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: NO such host is known in C:\wamp\www\fpdf.php`

`FPDF Error: Missing or incorrect image file:http://www.personal.psu.edu/rdl5038/dino.gif`

I have tried changing the image to an image that is stored locally on the machine and this works fine. As soon as I try an external link it fails. I have checked the php ini for the allow_url and this is turned on. REally stuck as there seems to be a security problem somewhere. Could it be something to do with access rights / read/write as the laptop is pretty locked down (work one - financial services)

Comment: Can you confirm that you can access that URL from the XP laptop via a browser?

Comment: Since the problem appears to depend on external links, I'd guess the "locked down" laptop includes a **firewall** that interferes with these connections.  This could be on a port-by-port basis, or it could be URL dependent.

Comment: Yes I can access the file through the browser and have a connection to the internet etc. BUt yes the laptop is very locked down and it has to connect through something called iPass. A very secure tunnel so I guess this could be the issue...

Comment: Looks to be a DNS issue rather than firewall as such. Check the image is being referenced by a canonical url, rather than a short LAN hostname

Comment: is the allow_url_fopen flag set in php.ini? And are you using PHP > version 4.3.0? http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: Can you access any external url from PHP? If not, your firewall is bloacking Apache/PHP from connecting to internet.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using cURL or another system to download to a temp file and uses it with FPDF.